# Nginx reverse proxy to subpage (non-root url)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want `http://example.com` to map to a *subpage* from somewhere else:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://somewhere.com/foo;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
 }
```

The problem is that this page will load stuff like

`<script src="/assets/script.js">`

which will then be attempted to get loaded from `http://example.com/assets/script.js` - but this will actually go to `http://somewhere.com/foo/assets/script.js` instead of `http://somewhere.com/assets/script.js`

So how can I convince nginx to just map the root domain - `http://example.com` to `http://somewhere.com/foo` and everything else to `http://somewhere.com/*`?

I tried many things but couldn't get it to work...

Comment: Did you solve your problem?